# Do Wasatch rail warriors have power points?

Tags: deadlands-reloaded

Under rail warriors, for Wasatch, it says

> They
>   gain a single Weird Science Power with a
>   trapping of your choice, and a d10 in the
>   appropriate skill.

Do they have power points, or is this like an at-will power from DnD 4e?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent to 'at-will' powers in Savage Worlds and in Deadlands if a character has access to an Arcane Background or Weird Science device, you need to know how many Power Points they have. Due to the way the stats for the different rail warriors are laid out in the Marshal's Guide, I would say that this is an unintended omission. For example, Black River specifies 10 Power Points for their powers.

Given that Mad Scientists start with 20 Power Points per device/power, I would give Wasatch Rail Warriors 20 Power Points for whatever Power you give them.